# How to notify UI of change with readonly property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-3.0

In WPF, I have a property with only a get{}.  The value is coming from the return of method.  NotifyPropertyChanged is often used within a property set{}.  It can then notify the UI and the updated value is displayed.  But with a get{} only, there isn't a way of detecting if a new or different value is available since you have to execute the method to check.

Is there some way to update the UI without having to keep a local value that contains the last value from the method, in which case a compare would need to be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> But with a get{} only, there isn't a way of detecting if a new or different value is available since you have to execute the method to check.

The problem boils down to this: What is changing the property?  The method that changes the property should call your `NotifyPropertyChanged` with the name of the property, which will, in turn, cause WPF to refetch the value and update the user interface.

WPF doesn't care *where* the `PropertyChanged` event gets raised - it just listens for it, and refreshes the binding as needed.

---

Edit in response to comment:

It sounds like this may be the result of performing some operation upon your Model class.  In this case, it's common that you know that one or more properties *may* change, but not necessarily which ones.  If your Model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you can subscribe to that and "bubble up" the notifications to the UI via your `NotifyPropertyChanged` method.  If it does not, however, there is another option.

If you know that one or more properties may change, you can raise a `PropertyChanged` event with `string.Empty` as the `PropertyName` in the EventArgs.  This will cause **all** bound properties to get refreshed by WPF.  This is likely just a matter of putting something like this in your code:

```
this.Model.DoSomething(); // This will change 1+ properties
this.NotifyPropertyChanged(string.Empty); // Refresh our entire UI
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this everywhere, however, as it does add overhead - but it's often the cleanest solution if you don't know which properties will change when you perform an operation.

Comment: That method is coming out of the model.  It doesn't seem correct that I should be passing in UI property names to the model...right?

Comment: @4thSpace: Does the model implement INPC?  If so, you can subscribe to it and "pass along" the property changed events.  If not, how do you currently know when a value changes?

Comment: I like the model implements INPC tecnique (but not the string.empty one above).  Can you show what this will look like in the UI?  I have a difficult time understanding because "MyPropertyName" used in the model is kind of just floating around.  How do you get the UI to take notice?

Comment: +1, had no idea you could raise `PropertyChanged` with an empty string to refresh all subscribers

Comment: @4thSpace: If your model implements INPC, your UI can just bind to Model.MyPropertyName (assuming the VM adds a "Model" property to return the model itself)

Comment: I did implement this in the model.  I have PropertyChanged("MyProperty") in the model at the point where the property will change (inside model method).  The property exist in the viewmodel and not in the model.  Not sure if I did it right.  So MyProperty isn't in the model since ViewModel.MyProperty does a get() on the Model.MyMethod.  ...after following NotifyPropertyChanged(), I see PropertyChanged is null.  Any ideas why that is?

Comment: @4thSpace: If the property isn't in the model, then this won't work.  If it's that your ViewModel property calls and returns a *method* from the model, the ViewModel should call teh method then raise PropertyChanged.  But this is odd - it won't get called unless you actually fetch the value...something has to know to update...

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Where you change the source data you would need to fire the INotify on the property. Here is an example.

```
private int _myvalue = 3;

  public bool MyProperty
    {
        get { return IsAProperty(); }
    }

public bool IsAProperty()
{
    return _myvalue + 1 == 4;
}
public void SetValue(int value)
{
    _myvalue = value;
    NotifyPropertyChanged(MyProperty);
}
```

Comment: `NotifityPropertyChanged` needs `string` parameter. It is strange this answer is upvoted while being incorrect and *messy* (what is a purpose of calling method `IsAProperty()` from a setter???).

Comment: If you set it up using reflection you can pass in the property itself.  Notice this answer is almost 4 years old.  There are some newer frameworks now that allow you to do this in a cleaner manner.  Instead of complaining in comments about an answer, if you feel it is incorrect then you should edit the answer to benefit the entire community.